# Fill Bootstrap modal with content from AJAX request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Here is my code which is calling the file shipper_modal.html file. I want to call this through an AJAX request and put the response in to a Bootstrap modal. This is not working.

```
$('.modalLink1').click(function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "shipper_modal.html", 
    cache: false:
    function(result) {
      $(".modal-content").html(result);         
    })            
  })
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Check the console to see the error, then refer to https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax to see what the syntax for this should look like

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('.modalLink1').click(function(){
  $.ajax({
    url: "shipper_modal.html",
    cache: false,
    success: function(result) {
      $(".modal-content").html(result);
  }});           
});
```